# HTML: 2 navigations causing problems

Tags: html, css, nav

I am having a great deal of frustration over coding the following design in css and html. I need two navigations (one grey and the other black) that possesses a simple paragraph tag for the "Call us" and then 2 buttons (seen on the top-right). The first button is simple, it opens the viewers email client but secondly is a search bar which needs to expand upon click. I am not sure how to do this in javascript/css. In the second navigation I can only get the h1 tag to float right next to the navigation (home). How would I code these two navigations in html and css?

*I already know how to format the backgrounds in gradients and colour, its the placing of content I need help with*

All help is appreciated with extreme gratitude! :)

[image: Photoshop Design]

EDIT:
Code Added (it is no where near correct)

```
<div id="top-nav-bar">
<div class="container">

 <ul class="top-nav">
 <li><p>Call us 1234 567 891</p><li>

 <li> <a href="mailto:"><img src="img/mail.png"/></a></li>
 <li><form class="sidebar-search"><div class="input-box"><a class="remove"href="javascript:;"></a><input type="text"></input><input class="submit" type="button"   value="text"></input></div></form></li>
 </ul>

 </div>
 </div>

 <header id="header"> 

 <div class="container">
 <div class="sixteen columns">  

 <nav id="nav">

 <ul>
    <li class="h1-logo"><h1>Logo</h1></li>
    <li><a href="index.html">home</a></li>
    <li><a href="properties.html">lease</a></li>
    <li><a href="manage.html">manage</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.html">contact</a></li>
 </ul>
 </nav>

 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

i think this code help You to develop Your site ahead. Goodluck, if You have any problem just write to me.

**HTML**

```
<div class="top-menu">
    <h1>Call on 5455234523523</h1>
    <div>
        <a href="">mail</a>
        <div class="search-box">
            <span id="search">search</span>
            <input id="search-input" type="text" />
        </div>    
    </div>
</div>
<div class="bottom-menu">

</div>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
    font-size: 10px;
    font-family: tahoma;
    color: #fff;
}
a {
    color: #999;
    text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;    
}
.top-menu, .bottom-menu {
    clear: both;
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.top-menu {
    background-color: #000;
}
.bottom-menu {
    background-color: #999;    
}
.top-menu h1 {
    float: left;
    font-size: 11px;
    margin: 0 0 0 10px;
    font-weight: normal;
    padding: 0;
}
.top-menu > div {
    float: right;
    width: 200px;
}
.top-menu > div * {
    float: left;
    margin: 0 5px;
}
.top-menu input {
    display: none;
    width: 100px;
}
.top-menu #search {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$('#search').click(function(){
    $('#search-input').toggle();
});
```

**DEMO**

http://jsfiddle.net/LZYsA/